# How to export a reference to a (JavaScript) class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to add some type information to a legacy JavaScript project. I added a `d.ts-File` and declared some types and some exports. The JavaScript file exports a instance and class. Like this:

```
const { Foo } = require('foo');

const stuff = {foo: new Foo(), FooClass: Foo};
module.exports = stuff;
```

This is my `d.ts`-file:

```
import { Foo } from 'foo';

export const foo: Foo;
//???How to declare the export of FooClass???
```

The best I got so far is `export class FooClass extends Foo{}`, but I would prefer not to introduce this virtual inheritence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the constructor of a class (`FooClass`) is `typeof ClassName` (`typeof Foo`), so:

```
import { Foo } from 'foo';

export const foo: Foo;
export const FooClass: typeof Foo;
```